# Date Filter - Merge Data

Tags: php, html, forms, date

I have the following code

```
<form method="get">
<fieldset> <!-- Set class to "column-left" or "column-right" on fieldsets to divide the form into columns -->
    <label>Datum Filter</label>
    <p>
        Vanaf
        <br>
        <select class="date1small-input" type="text" name="fd" />
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>                                      
        </select>

        <select class="date1small-input" type="text" name="fm" />
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>

        </select>
            <select class="date2small-input" type="text" name="fy" />
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        Tot en met
        <br>
        <select class="date1small-input" type="text" name="ud" />
            <option value="1">1</option>                
            <option value="31">31</option>                                      
        </select>

        <select class="date1small-input" type="text" name="um" />
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>

        </select>
            <select class="date2small-input" type="text" name="uy" />
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button class="button" type="submit">Filter</button>
    </p>
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

And it works fine but when I click on the 'filter' button, it sends the date like this to the browser:

```
URL?fd=1&fm=1&fy=2012&ud=1&um=1&uy=2012
```

I know this is normal, but is it possible to let it create the link like:

```
URL?fd=1/1/2012&ud=1/1/2012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With plain HTML this is not possible.

You can use a Javascript function, which submits the form data in the desired format.

Another approach could be URL rewriting at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a simple js function on the form's onsubmit, you can assemble any url you like. For example (to get `URL?fdate=1/1/2012&udate=1/1/2012`):

```
function set_date(e) {
    e.fdate.value = e.fd.value + "/" + e.fm.value + "/" + e.fy.value;
    e.udate.value = e.ud.value + "/" + e.um.value + "/" + e.uy.value;
    return true;
}
```

`<form action='...' onsubmit='return set_date(this);'>`